# Help with overwriting .phtml file in Magento 2.2.7

Tags: magento2, template, overrides, phtml

I need some advice on how to overwrite category description 'block?' from file

> /app/design/frontend/Mgs/mgsblank/Magento_Catalog/templates/category/description.phtml

I want to use my own module which I've created. I've tried many tutorials but still doesn't work.

Basically, I need to load my custom description.phtml with my module.

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

Using the layout file to override the phtml file.

**First way :**

```
<referenceBlock name="category.description">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Namespace_Modulename::path/to/my/file.phtml </argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

**Second way(the setTemplate method is deprecated so use this method) :**

```
<referenceBlock name="category.description" template="Namespace_Modulename::path/to/my/file.phtml"/>
```

**Third way :**

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View">
    <plugin name="very-unique-name" type="Namespace\Modulename\Plugin\Block" />
</type>
```

> Namespace\Modulename\Plugin\Block

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Plugin;

class Block
{
    public function beforeToHtml(\Other\Module\Block $block)
    {
        $block->setTemplate('Namespace\Modulename::path/to/my/file.phtml');
    }
}
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

here's my file catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance dc" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<referenceBlock name="category.description">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">MODULE_CategoryBanner::view/frontend/templates/catalog/category/description.phtml </argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
</page>
```

But I get an error

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'UNBXD_CategoryBanner::view/frontend/templates/catalog/category/description.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Catalog' block's name: 'category.description'
```

Comment: remove 'view/frontend/templates' from template file path in XML

Comment: ..and now it's working!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> **Your phtml File Path Should be view/frontend/templetes/view/frontend/templates/catalog/category/description.phtml**

**catalog_category_view.xml**

```
<referenceBlock name="category.description">
    <action method="setTemplate">
          <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">MODULE_CategoryBanner::view/frontend/templates/catalog/category/description.phtml </argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've managed to make it work. I made mistake with path to my .phtml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance dc" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<referenceBlock name="category.description">
    <action method="setTemplate">
          <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">UNBXD_CategoryBanner::catalog/category/description.phtml </argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
</page>
```